# ClickOnce Single vs Multiple Solutions Deployment

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, ms-office, clickonce

I've been trying to create deployment for a VSTO Word solution. I have two projects: an add-in and a template. I opt for ClickOnce as auto-updates will be implemented later on.

I created separate ClickOnce installers for both the add-in and template. But the drawback with that one is the add-in must know where the template will be installed since the two projects will be working together closely. I looked around MSDN and saw the article in deploying multiple office solutions in a single ClickOnce deployment. See below for links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465290.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2009/05/20/deploying-multiple-office-solutions-in-a-single-installer.aspx

I followed through the steps and tested the installation. The two projects are installed under one location but the template is not there. I modified the installer project to include the template and now it is being copied to the directory upon installation. When I open the template through code from the add-in, it produces an error and says it cannot find the VSTO of the template. I checked the installation folder and there are no VSTOs there.

I tried publishing the Template project as a stand-alone. The installation is okay and when I open the template, it is able to load the VSTO properly from the installation folder ClickOnce used.

I'm confused as to what I'm doing wrong. At the same time, is there any other difference I should know when putting two Office projects under one ClickOnce deployment, particularly Template type projects. I've read somewhere that ClickOnce does not go well with Template project types.